# Car Seat policy on Avianca

Tags: luggage, children, child-safety-seats, avianca

I'm flying Avianca, on international flight, Los Angeles to São Paulo (LAX-SAO), with a 3-year-old child.

Can I check-in a car seat for free?
Can I take a car seat with me in flight for free?

I can't find this information anywhere.

Comment: While they have extensive information about babies (under 2 years old), for whom a car seat is actually required if they have their own seat, I can’t find any relevant information for children or about car seats. I would think your best bet is to either call them or contact them on Twitter.

Comment: Their [Special baggage](https://ayuda.avianca.com/hc/en-us/sections/12994299323035-Special-baggage) web page doesn’t cover this. I suggest you contact them, via Whatsapp should work